# Log4j - Add filter to appender in Groovy

Tags: grails, groovy, log4j

I don't really have any relevant groovy experience so far and now I am trying to log only a few messages into a file from my grails app. I have set up log4j (1.2.17) in `Config.groovy` and a simple file appender is up and running.

Now what I want to do is filter the messages and only log the ones that match a regex. I think I should use a regexfilter for this, but I am simply unable to add the filter to the mentioned appender.

What I have now

```
    log4j = {
        appenders {
            console....
            file name: 'file', file: '*.log', layout: pattern(conversionPattern: "..."), filter: 
                regexFilter(pattern: "...", onMatch: "ACCEPT", onMismatch: "DENY")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Should be smth like `file( name: ... ) { regexFilter() }`

Comment: Unfortuantely, it doesnt seem to work for me.

Answer (score 1):

So I've tried what daggett suggested, but with no luck.

After a few (a lot) of trying, I've finally came up with a working solution, so if anyone is interested this works for me:

```
Logger.rootLogger.allAppenders.find{it instanceof FileAppender}?.addFilter({event -> event.getMessage().matches(***) ? Filter.ACCEPT : Filter.DENY} as Filter)
```

Just put it in the Config.groovy file.